# Designing a Win32api app

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

I'm pretty new to C++ and the more I read the more questions I have.

I want to convert an old C code of mine, which lists the devices on a machine, to a well designed C++ code that does the same.

As I have read, one of the most basic concept of C++ is isolation of Containers, Iterators and Algorithms.
That said, I came into conclusion that I should create 3 classes:

1. **DeviceInterface** - Holds a single interface info such as SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA, PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA and SP_DEVINFO_DATA
2. **DevicesInterfaceContainer** - Container that somehow holds all the devices information in form of DeviceInterface classes.
3. **DeviceInterfaceIterator** - Used by the algorithm to iterate over the items in the DevicesInterfaceContainer.

I didn't manage to implement it because I wasn't sure how.

1. Should the iterator be an output iterator that initializes the DevicesInterfaceContainer? Or whether the DevicesInterfaceContainer should initialize and acquire all the devices by its own?
2. What happens when an Win32 api fails in the constructor? Should I throw an exception? if so, what kind of exception? std::exception? std::runtime_error? or should I define a Win32Exception of my own that holds information about the LastError? (All I need is the last error in order to format the message.)

Something like:

```
class DeviceInterfacesList
{
public:
    DeviceInterfacesList(GUID& rtInterfaceGuid)
    {
        m_hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
            &rtInterfaceGuid,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
        );
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == m_hDevInfo)
        {
            throw Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    HDEVINFO m_hDevInfo;
};
```

I will be glad to get some guidance / good updated examples for using STL + win32api or anything that will clarify my questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Windows environment, you should return error code (HRESULTs) instead of throwing C++ exceptions (unless you keep these exception in your own code)

Comment: @SimonMourier: When following the RAII idiom to wrap system resources and API calls, use of C++ exceptions is mandatory. Those exceptions are also allowed to travel outside your code. In case noone catches one of your exceptions, the *unexpected* handler is invoked (which, by default, terminates the program).

Comment: @IInspectable - Sure, but, that's kinda my point as I was specifically talking about Windows programming which generally doesn't follow this idiom

Comment: @SimonMourier: The core API is exposed as a flat C interface. RAII is not an option here. Pretty much any C++ class library, on the other hand, does follow the RAII idiom. And since the OP does implement a C++ class over the Windows API, using C++ exceptions is an option.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use C++ STL, you problem could easier than you thought.
First, you need to design a class to hold the necessary information, 
that is "DeviceInterface". You can define the members and functions for this class.

You can use STL containers, such as deque or list as you container. The code would be like:

```
deque<DeviceInterface> DIList;
```

As for iterator, C++ STL provides you standard way to use it:

```
for(auto it = DIList.begin(); it != DIList.end; ++it){
    *it->getData();
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What about handling win33 errors (my second question)?